# Ubuntu Server: lost all files on external harddrive partition

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I have a remote nuc running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS with an external 2T USB hard drive.
At some point, the USB3 plug was half pulled out while it was running.
The plug was put back properly, but all the files had gone. An empty "lost+found" replaced them. Fsck etc found no files and no problems.
Having thought I'd lost them all, I repartioned the drive into two 1T halves. After that, /dev/sda1 mounted with all of the old files magically in place.
I had hoped my problems were over. One month passed.

However, after recent updates I rebooted the machine, and now, all the files are again gone. The backup copy on the new second partition are still there, but they are slightly out of date.

Again, fsck, TestDisk cannot find the files or a problem with /dev/sda1.

Firstly, How did the original files return?
Secondly, How do I do it again? Is there a better way than just repartitioning it again?
I'm a bit concerned about blindly trying for a second miracle here.

```
user@nuc:~$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x66a50ae2

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048 2000000000 1999997953 953.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2000001024 3907029166 1907028143 909.4G 83 Linux
```